# Why is return-to-libc much earlier than return-to-user?

Tags: security, linux-kernel, kernel, exploit

I'm really new to this topic and only know some basic concepts. Nevertheless, there is a question that quite confuses me.

Solar Designer proposed the idea of return-to-libc in 1997 (http://seclists.org/bugtraq/1997/Aug/63). Return-to-user, from my understanding, didn't become popular until 2007 (http://seclists.org/dailydave/2007/q1/224).
However, return-to-user seems much easier than return-to-libc. So my question is, why did hackers spend so much effort in building a gadget chain by using libc, rather than simply using their own code in the user space when exploiting a kernel vulnerability?

I don't believe that they did not realize there are NULL pointer dereference vulnerabilities in the kernel.

Comment: I haven't read it in detail but maybe it can't be sure that the exploiting user space process is the currently running process. Similarly, a context switch could mean their attack would fail. On the contrary, the kernel is always mapped in the address space regardless of which user space process is running.

Comment: Many ideas are "obvious" in hindsight.

Answer (score 2):

Great question and thank you for taking some time to research the topic before making a post that causes it's readers to lose hope in the future of mankind (you might be able to tell I've read a few `[exploit]` tags tonight)

Anyway, there are two reasons

1. `return-to-libc` is generic, provided you have the offsets. There is no need to programmatically or manually build either a return chain or scrape existing user functionality.
2. Partially because of linker-enabled relocations and partly because of history, the executable runtime of most programs executing on a Linux system essentially demand the libc runtime, or at least a runtime that can correctly handle `_start` and `cons`. This formula still stands on Windows, just under the slightly different paradigm of return-to-kernel32/oleaut/etc but can actually be more *immediately* powerful, particularly for shellcode with length requirements, for reasons relating to the way in which system calls are invoked indirectly by kernel32-SSDT functions

As a side-note, If you are discussing NULL pointer dereferences in the kernel, you may be confusing return to vDSO space, which is actually subject to a different set of constraints that standard "mprotect and roll" userland does not.

Answer (score 0):

Ret2libc or ROP is a technique you deploy when you cannot return to your shellcode (jmp esp/whatever) because of memory protections (DEP/NX).

Comment: Well, yes. In the early years, hackers could simply inject their own code by exploiting kernel vulnerabilities. After DEP/NX had emerged, hackers could not inject their code any more, but they could turn to return-to-user instead of using the much harder return-to-libc, from my point of view.

Answer (score 0):

They perform different goals, and you may engage with both.

### Return to libc

This is a buffer overrun exploit where you have control over some input, and you know there exists a badly written program which will copy your input onto the stack and return through it.  This allows you to start executing code on a machine you have not got a login to, or a very restrictive access.

Return to libc gives you the ability to control what code is executed, and would generally result in you running within the space, a more natural piece of code.

### return from kernel

This is a privilege escalation attack.  It takes code which is running on the machine, and exploits bugs in the kernel causing the kernel privileges to be applied to the user process.

Thus you may use return-to-libc to get your code running in a web-browser, and then return-to-user to perform restricted tasks.

### Earlier shellcode

Before return-to-libc, there was straight shellcode, where the buffer overrun included the exploit code, with knowledge about where the stack would be, this was possible to run directly.  This became somewhat obsolete with the NX bit in windows.  (x86 hardware was capable of having execute on a segment, but not a page).

> Why is return-to-libc much earlier than return-to-user?

The goal in these attacks is to own the machine, frequently, it was easy to find a vulnerability in a user-mode process which gave you access to what you needed, it is only with the hardening of the system by reducing the privilege at the boundary, and fixing the bugs in important programs, that the new return-from-kernel became necessary.